# Cannot search for posts of deleted user

Tags: discussion, bug

Fortunately, the posts of users whose accounts have been deleted remain available to view. However, I can no longer search for them. A search for "user:4032" yields nothing.

Is this a bug? Is there an alternative way to search?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It exists. You need to use SQL? for database of this site.

```
select 
   id as [Post Link]
  ,body
  ,owneruserid
  ,ownerdisplayname
from posts 
where ownerdisplayname = 'user4032'
```

Click **Run query** in the link below.
("japanese" should be a placeholder for this site. You may change it to any site you want to search)

https://data.stackexchange.com/japanese/query/edit/1552853

cf.

[How can I search for posts by Deleted Users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105976/how-can-i-search-for-posts-by-deleted-users)

(This question seems to have been asked over a decade ago, but it has been Viewed only "289 times" on Meta Stack exchange...)

Comment: うわすごっ！！--------

Comment: @Chocolate ユーザーの名前では出来るかは分からないです。コメントや回答でのやり取りかは、ちなみにこの質問で聞きたかった事がこれなのか。